# Transform class text to my domain name without http and www

Tags: javascript, jquery, dns

Using jquery or any script, how to change Text inside semantic `<p>` and `<h1>` with class='site-title' on my `<header/>` to my domain name without `http://` and `www.`.

Source:

```
<header role='banner'>
<h1 class='site-title'>My Blog Title</h1><!-- homepage header title -->
<p class='site-title' href='mylink'>My Blog Title</p><!-- other page header title -->
</header>
```

**TO** (if blog is using sub-domain):

```
<header role='banner'>
    <h1 class='site-title'>myblog.blogspot.com</h1><!-- change the text My Blog Title only -->
    <p class='site-title' href='mylink'>myblog.blogspot.com</p><!-- get my domain name witout http and www -->
    </header>
```

**OR** (if blog using self domain - not sub-domain):

```
<header role='banner'>
    <h1 class='site-title'>Myblog.com</h1>
    <p class='site-title' href='mylink'>Myblog.com</p>
    </header>
```